# F# query expression with a custom aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, database, f#, entity-framework-core, aggregate-functions

In my project I use [F# query expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) to query my database.

To code below calculates an average value grouped by column "Key":

```ml
open System.Linq

query{
    for row in ctx.MyTable do
    groupBy row.MyKey into g
    select (g.Key, g.Average(fun x -> x.MyValue))
}
```

I've realized that a median would be a better choice for my project than an `Average`. The thing is there doesn't seem to be support for calculating a median on the DB engine. However, I'd like to avoid fetching all the rows and calculating the median in memory, as there are too many of them and I need to save network bandwidth.

Is there any function that I could use here? Or do I need to write my own method entirely from scratch (if so - how)?

My DB Engine is MSSQL which contains a [PERCENTILE_COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function that might be useful in my case. Also, I use EntityFramework Core 3 and I noticed it contains some auxiliary functions like `EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute`, but I found nothing that could help with my problem.

Comment: EF Core currently does not support custom aggregates. If you ok to use third party extensions, I'll show you hot to do that with [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with F# query expressions, but you can always drop down to raw SQL in Entity Framework. Here's an example that computes the median of each customer's order amounts in the Northwind database:

```ml
ctx.Orders.FromSqlRaw(
    "select distinct \
    CustomerID, \
    percentile_cont(0.5) \
        within group (order by Freight) \
        over (partition by CustomerID) as FreightMedian \
    from Orders")
```